# How to get ElasticSearch result in steaming

Tags: elasticsearch

My ES index has 10 Billion records, When I issued the following query it took almost 10 minutes to get results: `{"wildcard":{"title":"*tvnews"}}`
So I'm wondering that is there a streaming API for restful query, i.e once ES get the result then immediate send it to me rather wait for the entire result ready. 
It should look like a streaming(get one just send one).

Comment: There must be another way to do that query. `wildcard` query with prefix wildcards are among the queries with the [worst performance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html), i.e. it's hard to do worse than that, especially with 10B docs. ES supports HTTP pipelining (in case of many requests) and conventional HTTP chunked transfer, but a bad query will still have bad performance, so you should prefer erring towards fixing your query than trying to return a response from a bad query as fast as possible.